# How to check if two large tables are identical?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I have 2 servers running one as a master and another slave. I want to check weather both the tables have the same data. How can i check and confirm this? The table has more than 23 million rows.

Also as a first step i tried to run 
`CHECKSUM TABLE tbl;`

But I am getting this error after 60 seconds:
`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Please advice.

Comment: According to this page http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55419, this seems a TCP timeout related issue.

You won't get any fast results, so better deal with the timeout first.

Comment: yes i know, but how can increase the time limit? what variable do i need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `mk-table-checksum`, which is part of the Maatkit utilities.

http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-checksum.html

Comment: it looks good, unfortunately im not authorized to install any new toolkits in the server.

Comment: mk-table-checksum does not need to be installed on the server. However, if you use it in --replicate mode (which is highly recommended; this is the ONLY way I know of checking consistency in a frequently-changing table), you will need to create a table for the checksums. You'll also need quite a lot of privileges.

Answer (score 1):

If your tables are set as master and slave then you shouldn't have to do this check. The binary synchronisation between the two assures you that they are identical. Doesn't it ?

If you are using one of the latest version of mysql you should also take a look at table partitionning : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html which would speed up a great deal access like checksums.

Comment: No, it really doesn't. They can easily become out of sync; replication does not ensure that they stay in sync, especially when master or slave loses power, and especially if innodb durability is not enabled on the master, or non-durable engines are used.

Comment: Interesting...I really thought the purpose of master-slave replication was that the table were synched. And in the case of a failure from one of the slave, as soon as it became available again it was resynched.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its 100% possible what you want to achieve, but at least one way to verify the state of the replication is to implement some kind of simple heartbeat mechanism, as described in the book [High Performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003067).

The method works with timestamps that are inserted in a table and verified every 20 secs. Together with the status report that `SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G` returns you get some accurate stats about the current state.

You see how many statements the slave is behind the master, or replication errors an such. If there are no errors or pending statements you should be fine enough to assume that at time t your tables are in sync.